# How to extend 'TextView' by two properties with the use of 'Tag'?

Tags: android, kotlin

I try to program a game with 12 coins in Android/Kotlin.
The coins are made by a **TextView** and created at runtime. All works fine so far.

```
   fun createCoin(coinNumber: Int) : TextView {
    val createdCoin = AppCompatTextView(this)

    createdCoin.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.simple_circle)
    createdCoin.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
    createdCoin.layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    createdCoin.text = (coinNumber +1).toString()
    createdCoin.textSize = 20F
    createdCoin.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
    createdCoin.tag = ??????

    return createdCoin
}
```

But now I need to save 2 more informations with each coin.

1. posIndex:Int
2. state:coinState

The enum:

```
    enum class coinState{
    UNKNOWN,
    TRUE,
    FALSE,
    Up,
    DOWN
}
```

Is there a possibility to store these two informations in an object/class and assign it to the **tag** in **TextView**. Or is there another simple way?

Thanks for your help
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way to save 2 object without any effort and additional classes :

```
tag = Pair(5, coinState.DOWN)
```

Comment: I like the Pair solution. Your line of code is working! But how can I read a value later on? And how can I change one value like coinState to UP?  myCoin.Tag....? did not show the Pair data. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes to read `Pair` you can use `val pairObject = view.tag` and get it's values. Instead of modifying you can set new `Pair` for this tag. You should be sure when reading tag of object that this is the same object that you use when setting data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way.
You can concatenate strings with a special delimeter, and then just read it as array of params by splitting by delimeter.

You can also use `Pair` like in answer above. In case if there are no parameters more than 2.

Or you can create own model

```
data class CoinParams(var name1: Type1, var name2: Type2, ....)
createdCoin.tag = CoinParams(1, "Some value", ...)
val params: CoinParams = createdCoin.tag as CoinParams
```

Example of string:

```
createdCoin.tag = "$value1||$value2"
params = createdCoin.tag.split("||")
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I would prefer the Pair solution. But if I not get it to work then the String or Class is an alternative. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
 tex.tag=Triple("x",3,5)
      var tagLogin=  loginAsTv.tag as Triple<String,Int,Int>
        println("tag ${tagLogin.first}")
```

You can try this.. or You ca set it on the basis of pattern

```
eg tag= position_coinindex
```